# Fixing Incorrect Python Array Format

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, arraylist

For some reason I cannot print either the entire array or loop through in the correct format.

Each entry in the array should be a separate URL.

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.get('https://newtrackon.com/api/live') 

#print(response.text)

my_input = [] 
my_input.append(response.text) 
#print(my_input) 

x = my_input[0]

print(x)

#for a in x:
#    print(a)
```

Comment: You need to split the string from the URL into elements of the list.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the string from the URL into elements of the list.

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.get('https://newtrackon.com/api/live') 

my_input = response.text.split("\n")

print(len(my_input))

# Remove the blank rows
my_input = list(filter(None, my_input))

print(len(my_input))
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, please accept the solution.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
    my_input = []
    my_input.append(response.text)
```

with

```
    my_input = response.text.split("\n\n")
```

the `response.text` returns all the urls as a single string

Comment: Splitting by two newline characters is a valid solution. Just note that the first assignment accomplishes nothing:  `my_input.append(response.text)`